# Better player issue in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, exoplayer

I have used **better player** lib as a video player but am not able to play videos more than 4 then after getting this error.

Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc, Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.640028, -1, null, [1920, 1080, 30.000002], [-1, -1])

This error comes only for android devices & Not sure how can I solve this error.
I have checked many links which are available on GitHub but did not get any conclusion on that.

Comment: @HarshHarsh have you solved this error?

Comment: No Still issue is there

Comment: @HarshHarsh I have solved it but after removing video_player plugin

Comment: Do I need to add some more specific or just remove video_player plugin?

Comment: @HarshHarsh I had only reoved video_player. you can try it if it will work then great for you

Answer (score 0):

inside  BetterPlayerConfiguration method add this line autoDispose: true,
it works for me.